# How to change the font size of specific text in strings.xml android

Tags: java, android, xml, font-size

Ok, I am writing an Islamic application for android in java. I have saved all the strings related to Arabic in the strings.xml file. I am displaying data manually in a recycler view by fetching data from strings.xml. The point I am confused about is that how can I **change the text size of a specific text written in strings.xml**.

For example, I have a text of Arabic verse where I have to put a symbol of the end of ayah at the end of verse.

The text size of arabic verse is large in the row_item which also makes the end of the ayah symbol large, but I want only the arabic verse text size to be large but the symbol text size to be small.

I want to know how to achieve this. Please if someone knows how i'd appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spans to style text at a character or paragraph level. Spans are not limited to text size, you can do a lot with it. For more details check [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans)

**Usage**

In the Adapter.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SpannableString string = new SpannableString(listdata[position]);

    string.setSpan(
            new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), // size
            5,  // start
            6,  // end
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // to exclude the inserted text.
    
    holder.textView.setText(string);

}
```

**I tested the above logic and the output as shown in the image.**
[Image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNPJW.jpg)